# Trying to use REST API to create repositories in sonatype Nexus

Tags: xml, rest, curl, repository, nexus

how do i create a repository through the REST API and was hoping someone could help me with the xml and curl script used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, if you are curious on how to do these things, you can use this article by us at Sonatype on how to learn the Nexus Repository 2 REST API: http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/01/26/learn-the-nexus-rest-api-automating-sonatype-nexus/

Secondly, here's an example one of our internal team members came up with:

This is a POST request to http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories. You can use it like this with curl:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @repo.json -u admin:admin123 http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories

Here's some sample content for the "repo.json" file referenced by the above, which shows how to create a proxy Maven repository. Note that the payload for creating other types of repositories will be different, use the article above to find out what those are.

```js
{
    "data": {
        "repoType": "proxy",
        "id": "somerepo",
        "name": "Some Repo Name",
        "browseable": true,
        "indexable": true,
        "notFoundCacheTTL": 1440,
        "artifactMaxAge": -1,
        "metadataMaxAge": 1440,
        "itemMaxAge": 1440,
        "repoPolicy": "RELEASE",
        "provider": "maven2",
        "providerRole": "org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.Repository",
        "downloadRemoteIndexes": true,
        "autoBlockActive": true,
        "fileTypeValidation": true,
        "exposed": true,
        "checksumPolicy": "WARN",
        "remoteStorage": {
            "remoteStorageUrl": "http://someplace.com/repo",
            "authentication": null,
            "connectionSettings": null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

#### TLDR

For Nexus3, use one of the [example scripts from here](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-scripting-examples/tree/master/simple-shell-example) to create your desired repository using the [Script API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api).

---

### Sonatype Nexus 3

The REST APIs have undergone (and I think are still undergoing) a bit of a revamp since version 2.

#### [Repositories API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/repositories-api)

The current [Repositories API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/repositories-api) is in BETA, and has only one endpoint to list repositories... so that won't work.

#### [Script API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api)

The [Script API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api) (v1, not BETA), allows tapping into the underlying Nexus libraries via [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/). You can use this API to create and execute a script to create a repository.

**e.g. Creating NPM repositories**

*Create a script to create NPM repositories, then execute the script.*

```sh
curl -X POST -u admin:admin123 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    http://127.0.0.1:8081/service/rest/v1/script \
    -d '{"name":"npm","type":"groovy","content":"repository.createNpmHosted('\''npm-internal'\'');repository.createNpmProxy('\''npmjs-org'\'','\''https://registry.npmjs.org'\'');repository.createNpmGroup('\''npm-all'\'',['\''npmjs-org'\'','\''npm-internal'\''])"}'
curl -X POST -u admin:admin123 --header "Content-Type: text/plain" 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/service/rest/v1/script/npm/run'
```

**Recommended reading:**

- [Writing Scripts](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api/writing-scripts)
- [Managing and Running Scripts](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api/managing-and-running-scripts)
- [Examples](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api/examples)

Comment: “example scripts from here” link is invalid

Comment: Thanks @bitweaver - updated the link with what I think is the current version. Correct me if I'm wrong. - https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-scripting-examples/tree/master/simple-shell-example

Comment: how to authenticate the nexus Rest Api through URL?